# Get a csv file to keep 174 tildes (commas) after removing the header

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am using Excel. I have a data file I need to submit to a client as a .csv. The data template has 174 columns in the header row, but they cannot accept the file with headers. The file never has any data after column 159, the rest are filler headers. Something changed to my version of Excel recently and every time I remove the header and save the file, the last 16 columns get removed. The client cannot load the file because it needs 174 tildes (commas). Does anyone have a solution within Excel or using VBA?

Comment: If you have **175** columns, you'll have 174 commas. If you delete the last 16 columns, 159 columns will remain. If you then save the file in csv-format, you'll be short of 16 commas in whichever version of Excel. You can prevent this by saving the file as-is, open the saved file in Notepad, delete the first line and save it. If you want to automate this in VBA, you need to explain where you will put the code and e.g. use the macro-recorder and record the steps that you're now making to create the csv-file and post the code to your question when we'll be able to take it from there.

Comment: tildes "~" are not commas "," So why not have 174 tildes in the first row?

Answer (score 1):

### Keep All Columns for CSV Export After Removing Headers When No Data In Right-Most Columns

- It is assumed that there are 3 workbooks:

  - the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`) in `xlsm-` or `xlsb-format`,
  - the original source workbook (file) containing the critical worksheet in any format,
  - the single-worksheet destination workbook which ends up being saved in `csv-format`.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportFile()
    
    Const sFolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const sFileName As String = "Test.xlsx"
    Const swsName As String = "Sheet1"
    
    Const dColumnsAddress As String = "FD:FS"
    Const dFolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const dFileName As String = "Test.csv"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlCSV
    
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    
    With Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
        .Worksheets(swsName).Copy ' copy as new one-worksheet workbook
        Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    
    With dwb
        Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = dFolderPath & dFileName
        With .Worksheets(1)
            ' Delete first row.
            .Rows(1).Delete
            ' Add single quotes to given columns of the new first row.
            .Rows(1).Columns(dColumnsAddress).Value = "'"
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        .SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=dFileFormat            
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "File exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```